# Building a simple tree structure

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I'm trying to build this simple tree:

> ```
> Multiverse
> |     
> |--- Universe
>     |
>     |--- Supercluster
>         |
>         |--- Galaxy
>             |
>             |--- Andromeda
>             |
>             |--- Milky way
> ```

I came up with this simple method which recursively walk a tree:

```java
/**
 * recursively walk a tree structure
 */ 
public static void recursive(TreeViewItem treeNode){

        System.out.println(treeNode.getText());

        Iterator<TreeViewItem> itr = treeNode.getItems().iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem) itr.next();
            recursive(item);
        }
}
```

Is there a better way or more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're visiting and printing the tree elements in a depth-first manner, so `depthFirstPrint` would be a much better name than "recursive" (which is always a terrible name for any recursive function).

You didn't need this cast:

> ```
> TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem) itr.next();
> ```

because you correctly declared the iterator as `Iterator<TreeViewItem> itr`

As of Java 1.5, you can use a for-each loop, which is simple and elegant:

```
for (TreeViewItem item : treeNode.getItems()) {
    depthFirstPrint(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are three kinds of recursive [binary tree traversals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal): pre-order, in-order, and post-order.  You've implemented pre-order traversal, so I suggest naming your function `preOrderTraversal()`.

Your function is actually doing two things: traversing the tree *and* printing each node.  It would be nice to separate them, so that you have a generic tree traversal algorithm, and a separate place to specify what to do with each node as it is encountered.  With Java ≤ 7, this can be done using a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  In Java 8, the visitor pattern can be much simpler, since the language allows functions to be passed around easily:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

…

public static void preOrderTraversal(TreeViewItem treeNode, Consumer<TreeViewItem> action) {
    action.accept(treeNode);
    for (TreeViewItem child : treeNode.getItems()) {
        preOrderTraversal(child, action);
    }
}

// Call that code with
preOrderTraversal(rootNode, (TreeViewItem node) -> System.out.println(node.getText()));
```

Your `TreeViewItem` class could have a `public Iterator<TreeViewItem> iterator()` method, so that `TreeViewItem` implements `Iterable<TreeViewItem>` to iterate of the children directly, without having to call `.getItems()`.  Whether you want to make this change depends on whether there might be anything else in a `TreeViewItem` that might be worth iterating over, besides the child nodes.